# Typescript requires mithril import that breaks in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, mithril.js

Currently translating my javascript app to typescript. Previously I was just using `m()` and `Vnode` without any imports, but typescript wants needs to include `import m, { Vnode } from 'mithril';` so it knows what they are.

The problem is when this compiles it adds the `import m from 'mithril';` to the top of the new js file. For some reason having that import breaks the app. I'm not entirely sure how it's able to work without that import, or why the import breaks it. This is for a chrome extension, and the error logging is very unhelpful, so I don't know what the specific error even is. The app just whitescreens.

Currently I am trying to fix this problem by writing a script that just deletes that import from every file, but I was wondering if there was a way to either omit that import in the first place/not have it break the javascript.

Comment: Try “import type { … } from …”

Comment: Doing that fixes the issue on the js side, but I get 'm cannot be used as a value since it was imported as a type' in the ts

Comment: have you tried importing the types https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/mithril?

Comment: I've imported types. If I import m the types are all there it just breaks javascript

Comment: `m` is just the default export. you probably want to destructure from within the default export. see https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/mithril/index.d.ts

Comment: or see here for a working example https://github.com/spacejack/mithril-ts-example

Comment: perhaps you can elaborate further on breaking the app

Comment: There's no error messages the entire app just won't load

Comment: Seems like //@ts-ignore is a key ;)

Answer (score -1):

Solved this by just putting

```
declare let m: any;
```

at the top of my file and hoping I'm using m right. This satisfies the typescript and doesn't get translated into the JS

That's not an ideal solution, so what I'm currently doing is adding this line to the `find . -type f -name '*.js' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' '/import m from/d'`

This effectively finds and deletes every mithril import

Comment: by using `any` you're losing all type safety, which defeats the point of using TS at all

Comment: It's not ideal and I'm still trying to find another way to do it, but I'm not primarily using typescript for type safety on the m specifically, so that's what I currently have to just keep the code running